# add option to choose different chat id for telegram bot

Tags: php, telegram-bot

I made a simple telegram bot with PHP to copy and send any messages that receives to another group
but how can I give the option to user in the bot to choose different groups to send
for example to group A or B

```
   $msgID = $updates["message"]["message_id"];

file_get_contents($link."/copyMessage?chat_id=GroupA&from_chat_id=999999&message_id=$msgID&disable_notification=true");
file_get_contents($link."/copyMessage?chat_id=GroupB&from_chat_id=999999&message_id=$msgID&disable_notification=true");
```

Answer (score 2):

I think sending message with buttons it's better way to that.

It'll be like this:

1. User sends /start command
2. User sends any message
3. Bot reply user's message with buttons
4. User chooses a button
5. Bot copies message to selected chat
6. Bot answers user with success or fail

Use this code:

```php
# Configuration that you need to fill

# Bot token obtained from @BotFather
define('BOT_TOKEN', 'Put your bot token here');

# Chat IDs Or Usernames that messages will be copied to
$chats =
[
    # Username/ID  => 'Chat title'
    '@MyOwnGroup' => 'The bot creator group',
    '1265170068' => 'My own account'
];

# Function to call any Bot API method
function bot(string $method, array $data = [])
{
    $api_url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . BOT_TOKEN . "/$method";
    if (count(data) > 0)
    {
        $api_url .= '?'.http_build_url($data, '', '&');
    }
    return file_get_contents($api_url);
}

# The update data, Received from Telegram
$update = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

# Handle if new message received
if (property_exists($update, 'message') && $update->message->text !== '/start')
{
    $message = $update->message;

    $buttons = ['inline_keyboard' => []];

    foreach ($chats as $chat_id => $chat_title)
    {
        array_push($buttons['inline_keyboard'], [['text' => $chat_title, 'callback_query' => $chat_id]]);
    }

    # Sending message with buttons to get which group the user wants
    bot('sendMessage', [
        'chat_id' => $message->chat->id,
        'text' => 'Select which group you want to send the message..',
        'reply_to_message_id' => $message->message_id,
        'reply_markup' => json_encode($buttons)
    ]);
}


# Handle if one of buttons was pressed
if (property_exists($update, 'callback_query'))
{
    $callback_query = $update->callback_query;

    # Copy the message
    $result = bot('copyMessage', [
        'from_chat_id' => $callback_query->message->chat->id,
        'message_id' => $callback_query->message->message_id,
        'chat_id' => $callback_query->data
    ]);

    if ($result->ok == true)
    {
        bot('answerCallbackQuery', [
            'callback_query_id' => $callback_query->id,
            'text' => 'Message was sent successfully!'
        ]);
    }
    else
    {
        bot('answerCallbackQuery', [
            'callback_query_id' => $callback_query->id,
            'text' => 'Message sending failed!',
            'show_alert' => true
        ]);
    }
}
```